# Is there an annotation alternative of a Spring Mvc controller property declared with XML?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am reading a book and the author declared a Controller in application context file like this :

```
<bean name="/nominee/*"
   class="com.springinpractice.ch03.web.NomineeController"
   p:thanksViewName="nominee/thanks"/>
```

I have found the annotation alternative for the bean name which is this one for the controller class:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/nominee/*")
```

but I want to find the annotation alternative for the thanksViewName property.

Here is the code of the controller class:

```
package com.springapp.mvc;

import com.springapp.model.Member;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;


@Controller
@RequestMapping("/nominee/*")
public final class NomineeController {
    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(NomineeController.class);

    private String thanksViewName;

    public void setThanksViewName(String thanksViewName) {
        this.thanksViewName = thanksViewName;
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public Member form()
    {
        return new Member();
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String processFormData(Member member)
    {
        log.info("Processing nominee: " + member);
        return thanksViewName;
    }
}
```

Any ideas?
Thank you.

Comment: If you're filling in the view name with an immediate value then what's the point of having it as anything other than a string in the first place? Type it in the class; you can always set it if you need to, or make it be a normal Spring annotated property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this -

```
private String thanksViewName = "nominee/thanks";
```

If you want to read the view name from some config then use the below annotation on the property.

```
@Value( "${view.thanksViewName }" )
```

Comment: It worked.But using pure java code means that there is no annotation alternative for this property?